# JQuery não carrega efeito obtido através de um serviço

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

Vou tentar expor meu problema da melhor forma possível.

Tenho uma pagina feita em HTML e tenho um serviço feito em Java que me retorna um html.

Nessa minha pagina html utilizo uma função ajax para carregar os dados desse serviço até ai funciona tudo bem, porém tenho alguns efeitos que quando o usuário clica em abre uma div utilizando JQuery não funciona.

Será que pq estou trazendo o html de outro lugar ele não está carregando alguma coisa?

Aqui a pagina com o serviço funcionando: [LINK](http://williamvillar.com.br/assets/Detalhe.html?valorAplicado=100000&meses=24&selic=14.15&di=14.13&txAdmin=2&td=0.20&cdb=117&cdb_pre=15.5&lci=92&fundo=104&pagina=detalhe)

Aqui a pagina estática sem o serviço [LINK 2](http://williamvillar.com.br/assets/simulacao_detalhado.html)

Clique nos + para fazer os testes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O arquivo "http://williamvillar.com.br/assets/js/materialize.min.js" deve ser carregado após o fim da requisição ajax, senão os elementos não terão seus listeners carregados, ou seja, não detecta clicks.

Após esta linha:

```
if(responseText) {
```

Você pode usar o bloco abaixo para corrigir seu problema:

```
$.getScript( "/assets/js/materialize.min.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: @ Jhonnyjks, obrigado! Como posso carregar o arquivo depois da chamada?

Comment: Editei a resposta pra te informar isso!

Comment: Sou novo aqui, então se te ajudei, marca minha resposta como útil! ;-)

Comment: claro que maro sim! Deu certo aqui muito obrigado!!!! Se pudesse te mandava 1000 pontos rsrs...
Abraço

Comment: Certo! Dedique sempre um tempinho ao SO também! Vamo compartilhar conhecimento e deixar essa versão PT bem farta!

Comment: estava testando nos browsers aqui e não funcionou no Edge e no celular, sabe me dizer onde pode estar o problema?

Comment: Qual o link com essa correção que te indiquei?